# Example from Google to automate uploading a YouTube video gives "Error 400: invalid_request"

Tags: google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am following the guide here to upload a video to YouTube using their Data API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

When I run the sample code with this command:

```
python upload_video.py --file="/var/www/html/share/test.mp4" --title="Test" --privacyStatus="unlisted" --noauth_local_webserver
```

It asks me to:

```
Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&client_id=snippped
```

After doing so, I receive this error:

[image: Error from sample script in a browser]